# How to detect Codeen Proxy

Tags: php, proxy

I have small proxy-list site and I would like to remove from my list all Codeen proxies. Do you have any idea how to detect them? (I prefer PHP language)

I tried to compare proxyjudge results of codeen servers and normal proxies, but there is no diffrences.

I would be really grateful for any ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Parse out the list of [all Codeen proxies](http://fall.cs.princeton.edu/codeen/) and remove them from your list.

Comment: The link in this answer seems dead.